# About exterior measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, analysis

Given sets $E_n \subset  [0,1]$ with $\sum m^*E_n =\infty$, determine whether

$$m^*(\limsup E_n)>0$$

(we define $\limsup E_n=\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}\cup_{n=k}^{\infty}E_n$).

**My attempt:** I think $m^*(\limsup E_n)>0$. I want to use contradiction: if $m^*(\limsup E_n)=0$, then $\limsup E_n$ doesn’t contain any open interval ... but I don’t know what to do next .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $E_n=[0,1/n]$ ($n\geq1$)?

We have $m^* E_n = 1/n$ so that $\sum m^* E_n$ diverges, and $\limsup E_n = \{0\}$.

Comment: Wow...I think a whole night ...I total wrong...

Comment: Real analysis is so hard...